# removing markers from linechart in mschart

Tags: r, mschart, officer

I am using `officeR`and `mscharts` to create powerpoints from R. I have ran into a problem where I dont know how to remove the markers from the line charts. The `mschart` package says that from version 0.3.1 you are able to have line charts with or without markers but I can't figure out how. Below is an example of a line chart which includes markers.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mschart)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "car") %>% 
  mschart::ms_linechart(x = "car", y="mpg") %>% 
  mschart::chart_theme(legend_position = "t",
                       axis_text_y = fp_text(font.size = 8),
                       axis_text_x = fp_text(font.size = 6)
  ) %>% 
  print(preview=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `chart_settings` where you can specify the `style` with "line", so it will only plot a line without the markers. Here a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mschart)
library(officer)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "car") %>% 
  mschart::ms_linechart(x = "car", y="mpg", group = NULL) %>% 
  mschart::chart_theme(legend_position = "t",
                       axis_text_y = fp_text(font.size = 8),
                       axis_text_x = fp_text(font.size = 6)
  ) %>% 
  mschart::chart_settings(style = "line") %>%
  print(preview=TRUE)
```

Output:

[image]